# priority queue with lambda syntax is confusing

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, priority-queue

As per specification of priority queue

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

But why this odd syntax with Lambda?

```
// Using lambda to compare elements.
    auto cmp = [](int left, int right) { return (left ^ 1) < (right ^ 1); };
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> q3(cmp);
```

Why we need to pass cmp as an argument?

Answer (score 2):

Before C++20 [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) closure types are not *DefaultConstructible*; they have no default constructor. So you have to pass a lambda object to the [constructor of `std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue). (Closure types have copy and move constructor.)

> Copy-constructs the comparison functor `comp` with the contents of `compare`. Value-initializes the underlying container `c`.

Since C++20 if no captures are specified, the closure type has a defaulted default constructor. Then you can construct `std::priority_queue` without passing the lambda.

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> q3;
```

> Default constructor. Value-initializes the comparator and the underlying container.